# Socket doesn't send data until it is closed

Tags: java, python, sockets

i have a simple application which create a socket between java(server) and python(client).
The main function of the python code is to take data from user and send it to the server(java code)

here's the python code

```
import socket

client_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
client_socket.connect(("localhost", 5000))

while True:
    data = input("Enter data to send : ")
    if(data == 'q'):
        break

    client_socket.sendall(data.encode('utf-8'))

client_socket.close()
```

and here's the java code

```
    String fromclient;

    ServerSocket Server = new ServerSocket (5000);


    while(true) 
    {
        Socket connected = Server.accept();
        BufferedReader inFromClient = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader (connected.getInputStream()));
        fromclient = inFromClient.readLine();

        if ( fromclient.equals("q") ){
                connected.close();
                break;
            }else {
              System.out.println(fromclient);
         }
    }
```

when I write any text and click Enter, nothing goes to java code and nothing printed to the console, but when i send 'q' from python, the python code closed and all the data i wrote are now printed in java console.
I have no idea what is the reason of this, and how i can fix it.

Comment: Add some `System.out.println`s before and after `inFromClient.readLine()`.

Comment: In your java code the `accept()` and `new BufferedReader()` need to go outside of the loop. You don't want to create a new connection at every iteration of the loop.

Comment: I think you never will receive the 'q' command in your server (fromclient.equals("q")). The python client is breaking before send it.

Comment: You don't need to send it though. When the socket is closed, `readLine()` will return `null`.

Comment: i just take these two lines outside the loop and the code worked correctly, thank you all `Socket connected = Server.accept();` ,
  `BufferedReader inFromClient = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader (connected.getInputStream()));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Java code waits for a line-break, but the Python part does not send one (`input` provides no line-break in the string it returns).

Try

```
client_socket.sendall((data+'\n').encode('utf-8'))
```

---

As @Kayaman suggests, the `accept` is in a wrong place (and also is the `BufferedReader`).

```
Socket connected = Server.accept();
BufferedReader inFromClient = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader (connected.getInputStream()));
while(true) 
{
    fromclient = inFromClient.readLine();
```

would be a better order.

Also, Python client does not send the 'q' in its current form. So the `if` with the `fromclient.equals("q")` will not close the socket, the code will just die on the next `readLine()` instead. Re-order the Python part too:

```
data = input("Enter data to send : ")
client_socket.sendall((data+'\n').encode('utf-8'))

if(data == 'q'):
    break
```

Comment: This leads to print only the first word i write, and when i click enter and type a new word nothing is sent